# One Select box style in all browsers

Tags: html, css

I tested this CSS to make Select box in one style:

```
select::-ms-expand {
    width:12px;
    border:none;
    background:#fff;
}
```

But as you can see there are still differences.

Is there any way to make Select box to look same in all browsers?

[image]

Comment: It can be done for the most part, but takes some work. See this: https://github.com/filamentgroup/select-css

Comment: is there any solution without third-party library?

Answer (score 1):

So you're looking to do something like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="select-style">
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.select-style {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;

    background: #fff url("https://lh3.ggpht.com/O6M43xfWwf_sXtZk_3wv53tGmG6Y-Dtod3_gY6IyuJvEmzhYAcwuNxR1yqAJ9Zacu8vynktJ-w=w16") no-repeat 90% 50%;
}

.select-style select {
    padding: 5px 8px;
    width: 130%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
}

.select-style select:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: you should use  Reset CSS ,

try [this one](https://gist.github.com/anthonyshort/552543)